# Access Selectable helper

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

Is possible to access the jquery ui selectable helper on any of the events? (especially `start` event)

I need to add a special class to it, to avoid conflicts with other selectables

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I don't think jquery ui selectable has a helper. Do you mean you want to add a class to the elements that have been selected?

Comment: All selected items get class `ui-selected`. Do you want to know this ?

Comment: jquery selectable appends on `body` a div with class `ui-selectable-helper` - that's the one i am trying to access. (Hmmm..i think it can be only one `ui-selectable-helper` at a time on the `body`, so i could just get it using normal jquery selector)

Comment: @Raraitul, try it and make sure it works, if it does post it as the answer.